# Using foreign keys to delete entries in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

**The following setup will:**

- Allow me to delete existing entries
- Prevent me from creating new entries in `products`

This probably happens because entries gets created in `products` before `categories_products`. But I cannot create entries in `categories_products` before I know the product ID.

What would you do?

```
ALTER TABLE products
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_products
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES categories_products(product_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

**Tables**

```
categories:
id, name

categories_products:
category_id, product_id

products:
id, name
```

**Which order each entry gets created**

1. Create an entry in categories
2. Create an entry in product
3. Using the IDs from 1. and 2. to create a relationship between `categories` and `products`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your constraint backwards.  That foreign key should be on the `categories_products` table and referencing the `products` table, not the other way around:

```
ALTER TABLE categories_products
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_products
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: This works. But when I try to delete a category the entries in "products" and "categories_products" still remains.

Comment: @Cudos - then you need a similar constraint on category_id to the category table.  But you don't seriously want to delete a product if the category is deleted though do you?

Comment: Why not? If the category is gone the products need to disappear too.

Comment: @Cudos - seems like you would want to delete the relationship between the product and the category, but not the product itself.  What if the product was in more than one category for example?

Answer (score 0):

You have a **many-to-many** relation:

- Each product can have many categories.
- Each category can have many products.

So, you should add two foreing keys to support this type of relation. These foreign have to be added to the categories_products table:

```
ALTER TABLE categories_products
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_products FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
    REFERENCES products(id),
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_categories FOREIGN KEY (category_id)
    REFERENCES categories(id);
```

Then, to delete category and related products use a query like this:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DELETE c, cp, p
  FROM category c
    JOIN categories_products cp
      ON cp.category_id = c.id
    JOIN products p
      ON p.id = cp.product_id
WHERE
  c.id = 100;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

You also may want to add ON DELETE CASCADE clause, it will help you to delete the row from the parent table and automatically delete the matching rows in the child table. For example, next query will remove automatically related records in `categories_products` table:

```
DELETE FROM category id = 100;
```